# Why click event handler doesn't work after sorting the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and I have a table which is generated using a `foreach` loop. In each row generated, 2 buttons are made with a different number added to a `data` attribute.

After the page loads, dataTables kicks in and renders the table. I have an `onClick` handler that responds to the buttons when clicked.

However, when I sort table columns that dataTables is capable of doing, the buttons simply do not respond to the `onClick` handler.

What can I do to prevent dataTables from causing the buttons to do nothing when either of the sorting columns are used?

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `$('.button').click`, because those buttons are recreated when sorted, instead use `on` jquery event

```
$(document).on('click', '.button',function(){
  //your code
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'd like to mention I made a big change to my code. Instead of a foreach now, all the table row content is generated using DataTable's ajax option. The ajax PHP code generates the HTML buttons that loads into the table.

Comment: there is no way that this code doesn't works, use your selector, e.g. if your buttons got a class "test" then instead '.button' add '.test'

Comment: Your code is incorrect because jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function requires parameters in the following order: event, selector, handler. Besides attaching event to `document` element is error prone, it's better to narrow it to table body, like `$('#example tbody')`.

Comment: thnx for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delegated event handlers because your buttons most likely get recreated when table is redrawn.

Below is a sample code that you need to update to match your structure:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.button', function(e){
   // your code
});
```

Replace `example` with ID attribute of your table and replace `.button` with appropriate CSS selector for your buttons.

See [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.